# Unable to move files into devexpress file treelist

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have created a file treelist in my WinForms application. The files and folders are displayed in a correct way. But when I try to drag a file from my pc (for ex. from my desktop) to the application the draggednode and the target node are null. Moving folders within my application works fine. How to change my application that I can drag files into the folders in the application?

Code:

```
 class FileListHelper
{
    string rootPath;
    TreeList Tree;
    private DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn treeListColumn1;
    private DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn treeListColumn2;
    private DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn treeListColumn3;
    private DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn treeListColumn4;
    private DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn treeListColumn5;
    TreeListMenu folderMenu;

    public FileListHelper(TreeList tree)
    {
        Tree = tree;
        InitColumns();
        Tree.BeforeExpand += new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.BeforeExpandEventHandler(this.treeList1_BeforeExpand);
        Tree.AfterExpand += new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.NodeEventHandler(this.treeList1_AfterExpand);
        Tree.AfterCollapse += new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.NodeEventHandler(this.treeList1_AfterCollapse);
        Tree.CalcNodeDragImageIndex += new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.CalcNodeDragImageIndexEventHandler(this.treeList1_CalcNodeDragImageIndex);
        Tree.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.treeList1_DragDrop);
        Tree.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.treeList1_DoubleClick);
        Tree.PopupMenuShowing += new PopupMenuShowingEventHandler(Tree_PopupMenuShowing);
        Tree.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(this.treeList1_DragEnter); //added shows icons
        tree.CellValueChanged += new CellValueChangedEventHandler(tree_CellValueChanged);
        InitData();
        folderMenu = new TreeListMenu(Tree); 
        folderMenu.Items.Add(new DXMenuItem("Create New Folder",MenuAddClick));
        folderMenu.Items.Add(new DXMenuItem("Delete", MenuDeleteClick));

    }


    #region DragEnter
    void treeList1_DragEnter(object sender,DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor"))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        }
        else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            //ensure FileGroupDescriptor is present before allowing drop
        }
        else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("RenPrivateMessages"))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

    }
    #endregion DragEnter


    #region Rename
    void tree_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Caption =="Name")
        {
            if (e.Node["Type"] == "Folder")
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = e.Node["Info"] as DirectoryInfo;
                di.MoveTo(di.Parent.FullName+"//"+e.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                FileInfo fi = e.Node["Info"] as FileInfo;
                fi.MoveTo(fi.Directory.FullName + "//" + e.Value);

            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Popup Menu
    void Menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
    void Tree_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeListNode node = Tree.CalcHitInfo(e.Point).Node;
        if (node != null)
        {
            e.Menu = folderMenu;
            e.Menu.Tag = node;
            //e.Menu.Items.Add(new DXMenuItem("Create New Folder"));
        }
    }
    void MenuAddClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di;
        int ParentId = -1;
        TreeListNode curentNode = folderMenu.Tag as TreeListNode;
        TreeListNode folderParentNode;
        if (curentNode["Type"] == "Folder")
            folderParentNode = curentNode;
        else
            folderParentNode = curentNode.ParentNode;
        if (folderParentNode == null)
        {
            di = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);
        }
        else
        {
            ParentId = folderParentNode.Id;
            di=folderParentNode["Info"] as DirectoryInfo;
        }
        DirectoryInfo newDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(di.FullName + "\\New Folder");
        if (newDirectory != null)
        {
            Tree.FocusedNode = Tree.AppendNode(new object[] { newDirectory.FullName, newDirectory.Name, "Folder", null, newDirectory }, ParentId);
        }
        Tree.FocusedColumn = Tree.Columns["Name"];
        Tree.ShowEditor();
    }
    void MenuDeleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeListNode curentNode = folderMenu.Tag as TreeListNode;
        (curentNode["Info"] as FileSystemInfo).Delete();
        Tree.DeleteNode(curentNode);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Initializing TreeList
    void InitColumns()
    {
        this.treeListColumn1 = new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn();
        this.treeListColumn2 = new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn();
        this.treeListColumn3 = new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn();
        this.treeListColumn4 = new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn();
        this.treeListColumn5 = new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn();

        this.treeListColumn1.Caption = "FullName";
        this.treeListColumn1.FieldName = "FullName";

        this.treeListColumn2.Caption = "Name";
        this.treeListColumn2.FieldName = "Name";
        this.treeListColumn2.VisibleIndex = 0;
        this.treeListColumn2.Visible = true;
        this.treeListColumn2.SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending;
        this.treeListColumn2.SortIndex = 1;


        this.treeListColumn3.Caption = "Type";
        this.treeListColumn3.FieldName = "Type";
        this.treeListColumn3.VisibleIndex = 1;
        this.treeListColumn3.Visible = true;
        this.treeListColumn3.SortOrder = SortOrder.Descending;
        this.treeListColumn3.SortIndex = 0;
        this.treeListColumn3.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;

        this.treeListColumn4.AppearanceCell.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
        this.treeListColumn4.AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Far;
        this.treeListColumn4.Caption = "Size(Bytes)";
        this.treeListColumn4.FieldName = "Size";
        this.treeListColumn4.VisibleIndex = 2;
        this.treeListColumn4.Visible = true;
        this.treeListColumn4.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;

        this.treeListColumn5.Caption = "treeListColumn5";
        this.treeListColumn5.FieldName = "Info";
        this.treeListColumn5.Name = "treeListColumn5";


        Tree.Columns.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn[] {
        this.treeListColumn1,
        this.treeListColumn2,
        this.treeListColumn3,
        this.treeListColumn4,
        this.treeListColumn5});

    }

    private void InitData()
    {
        //int currentIncidentId=2;
        //rootPath = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        rootPath = "C:\\Data\\98-ProgrammData\\Maintenance\\Dossier\\"/*+currentIncidentId*/;
        InitFolders(rootPath, null);
    }

    private void InitFolders(string path, TreeListNode pNode)
    {
        Tree.BeginUnboundLoad();
        TreeListNode node;
        DirectoryInfo di;
        try
        {
            string[] root = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            foreach (string s in root)
            {
                try
                {
                    di = new DirectoryInfo(s);                   
                    node = Tree.AppendNode(new object[] { s, di.Name, "Folder", null, di }, pNode);
                    node.StateImageIndex = 0;
                    node.HasChildren = HasFiles(s);
                    if (node.HasChildren)
                        node.Tag = true;
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        InitFiles(path, pNode);
        Tree.EndUnboundLoad();
    }


    private void InitFiles(string path, TreeListNode pNode)
    {
        TreeListNode node;
        FileInfo fi;
        try
        {
            string[] root = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (string s in root)
            {

                fi = new FileInfo(s);
                node = Tree.AppendNode(new object[] { s, fi.Name, "File", fi.Length, fi }, pNode);
                node.StateImageIndex = 1;
                node.HasChildren = false;

            }
        }
        catch { }

    }


    private void treeList1_FilterNode(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.FilterNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeList tree = sender as TreeList;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tree.FindFilterText)) return;
        e.Node.Visible = IsNodeVisible(e.Node);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private bool IsNodeVisible(TreeListNode node)
    {
        if (node.ParentNode == null)
        {
            foreach (TreeListColumn column in node.TreeList.VisibleColumns)
            {
                object val = node[column.FieldName];
                if (val != null && val.ToString().ToUpper().Equals(node.TreeList.FindFilterText.ToUpper()))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return IsNodeVisible(node.ParentNode);
    }



    private bool HasFiles(string path)
    {                                     
        string[] root = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        if (root.Length > 0) return true;
        root = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        if (root.Length > 0) return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void treeList1_BeforeExpand(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.BeforeExpandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Tag != null)
        {
            Cursor currentCursor = Cursor.Current;
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            InitFolders(e.Node.GetDisplayText("FullName"), e.Node);
            e.Node.Tag = null;
            Cursor.Current = currentCursor;

        }
    }

    private void treeList1_AfterExpand(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.NodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.StateImageIndex != 1) e.Node.StateImageIndex = 2;
    }

    private void treeList1_AfterCollapse(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.NodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.StateImageIndex != 1) e.Node.StateImageIndex = 0;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Dragging
    private void treeList1_CalcNodeDragImageIndex(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.CalcNodeDragImageIndexEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node[treeListColumn3].ToString() == "Folder")
        {
            e.ImageIndex = 0;
        }
        if (e.Node[treeListColumn3].ToString() == "File")
        {
            if (e.Node.ParentNode == Tree.FocusedNode.ParentNode)
            {
                e.ImageIndex = -1;
                return;
            }
            if (e.ImageIndex == 0)
                if (e.Node.Id > Tree.FocusedNode.Id)
                    e.ImageIndex = 2;
                else
                    e.ImageIndex = 1;
        }
    }

    private void treeList1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
            TreeListNode draggedNode = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeListNode)) as TreeListNode;
            TreeListNode tagretNode = Tree.ViewInfo.GetHitTest(Tree.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Node;
            if (tagretNode == null || draggedNode == null) return;
            if (tagretNode[treeListColumn3].ToString() == "File")
            {
                if (tagretNode.ParentNode == draggedNode.ParentNode)
                    return;
                MoveInFolder(draggedNode, tagretNode.ParentNode);
            }
            else
            {
                MoveInFolder(draggedNode, tagretNode);
            }
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    void MoveInFolder(TreeListNode sourceNode, TreeListNode destNode)
    {

            Tree.MoveNode(sourceNode, destNode);
            if (sourceNode == null) return;
            FileSystemInfo sourceInfo = sourceNode[treeListColumn5] as FileSystemInfo;
            string sourcePath = sourceInfo.FullName;

            string destPath;
            if (destNode == null)
                destPath = rootPath + sourceInfo.Name;
            else
            {
                DirectoryInfo destInfo = destNode[treeListColumn5] as DirectoryInfo;
                destPath = destInfo.FullName + "\\" + sourceInfo.Name;
            }
            if (sourceInfo is DirectoryInfo)
                Directory.Move(sourcePath, destPath);
            else
                File.Move(sourcePath, destPath);
            sourceNode[treeListColumn5] = new DirectoryInfo(destPath);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Executing
    private void treeList1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as TreeList).FocusedNode[treeListColumn3].ToString() == "File")
            Process.Start(((sender as TreeList).FocusedNode[treeListColumn5] as FileSystemInfo).FullName, null);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

These two lines are null:

```
     TreeListNode draggedNode = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeListNode)) as TreeListNode;
     TreeListNode tagretNode = Tree.ViewInfo.GetHitTest(Tree.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))).Node;
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on those two lines to see what type the actually are and if your PointToClient is referencing the your TreeView?

Comment: Yes I have put a breakpoint on them. Both are null which is the problem because the method returns then. The PointToClient is referencing my TreeView. Within my application drag & drop works but when I try to add a file/folder from outside the application both nodes are null.

Comment: What I meant was is `e.Data` also null at that point in time. If not, what type is it

Comment: If I check e.Data it isn't null. It's type is: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataObject'

Comment: The e.Data at that point in time contains DataFormat.FileDrop, which is essentially an array of strings with the paths to the dropped files/folders (check `e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop).GetType().ToString()`. You need to parse that in such a way and not directly convert them to a TreeListNode.  Why the Tree.PointToClient is not properly identifying your TreeList's node, that you will need to investigate further

Comment: Why does this code work in my application for moving folders (source and target are not null) and not for folder/files I want to drag in? I think draggedNode and targetNode are okay then. I did already chechk the FileDrop string and it's correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63856/discussion-between-sybren-and-bernd-linde).